# Search is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i did search like this but it is not taking passed value in text box,can any one help me to solve this issue..thanks in advances........my model query is correct or any error is there......

if i enter in search term it is redirecting to search results page but it is showing blank results.......and it is saying **invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

if i print `last_query()` in that it is showing Like below.....

```
  SELECT * FROM (`clients`) WHERE  `clientName`  LIKE '%%'
```

This is My Controller:

```
    class Client extends CI_Controller{

        public function __construct(){
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model("client_model");
            $this->load->model("interview_model");
            $this->load->model("candidate_model");
            $this->load->model("requirement_model");
        }

    function search()
        {
             $search_term = $this->input->post('search');
             $data['query'] = $this->client_model->search_client($search_term); 
             echo "<pre>"; print_R($this->db->last_query()); exit;
            $data['page_title'] = "Search Results";
            $this->layout->view("client/search",$data);
        }


    }
```

Model:

```
    function search_client($search_term)
        {
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('clients');
            $this->db->like('clientName',$search_term);

            // Execute the query.
            $query = $this->db->get();

            // Return the results.
           return $query->result_array();
        }
```

This is form in index.php(View):

```
<form action="<?php base_url();?>client/search">
                          <input type="text" name="search" id="search" style="width:180px" placeholder="Search here..." />&nbsp;
                          <input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"  /></form>
```

This is search.php(view):

```
    <?php  foreach($query as $client){ ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $client->clientName;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $client->clientSName; ?></td></td>

            <td>
   <?php } ?>
```

Comment: check the number of resulting records using `echo $query->num_rows();` in the model

Comment: 20 it is giving in my database 20 records are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this line:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php base_url();?>client/search">
```

to this:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url();?>client/search">
```

and try the following approch:

```
function search_client($search_term){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('clients');
    $this->db->like('clientName',$search_term);

    // Execute the query.
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if($query->num_rows()>0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: No it is showing like this..Severity: Warning

Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Filename: client/search.php

Line Number: 165

Comment: @Arun which is line no. 165 ? inner foreach or outer ?

Comment: <?php  foreach($query as $client){ ?> this line

Comment: 20 it is giving in my database 20 records are there

Comment: total i have 20 it is showing 20..but in our case it is suppose to show only searched record

Comment: So it means the problem is the value of the searched criteria you are passing! check the value of `$this->input->post('search');` in the controller!

Comment: Also add `method="POST"` to the form tag!

Comment: Actually searched term in textbox is not passing this is last_query() SELECT *
FROM (`clients`)
WHERE  `clientName`  LIKE '%%'